# Scrolling on tablet is disabled

Tags: scroll, tablet, landscape

I have a website that doesn't scroll on tablets when they are used in horizontal mode. It scrolls fine if I put the device in vertical mode, and then turn it horizontal with screen rotation activated (checked with Chrome and Firefox).

http://powerflex-fhp.nl/

I'm having trouble debugging since I don't know how to inspect a website's code on a tablet like I would on PC.
This issue does not occur on phones, nor on any PC browser.

Does anyone know what is going on?
Alternatively, could you point me to developer tools for tablet browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look through Chrome's remote debugging if your device is compatible: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

As for solving your specific issue, you haven't provided enough details on your code and the tablet you're testing on for SO to give you a helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know this option.

I found the problem, a option called "swipe body" from Shiftnav plugin was the clue of blocking scroll.